# lua + visual c++ 2008: fatal error LNK1107

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, lua

I'm getting started with lua. I have a very simple project but I can't get it to run. I keep getting the same error: fatal error LNK1107: file broken or damaged: cannot read at 0x2C3C   file: lua.h line:1

help would be greatly appreciated

thanks in advance

c++ code

```
#include <iostream>


extern "C"
{
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "luaconf.h"
}


int main()
{
int s=0;

lua_State *L = lua_open();

// load the libs
luaL_openlibs(L);

//run a Lua scrip here
luaL_dofile(L,"foo.lua");

printf("\nI am done with Lua in C++.\n");

lua_close(L);

return 0;
}
```

lua code

```
io.write("Please enter your name: ")
name = io.read() -- read input from user
print ("Hi " .. name .. ", enjoy hacking with Lua");
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're trying to link a header file into your program.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more? I know I'm supposed to reference these libraries but they're already there, as far as I know.

Comment: I don't know about projects and such but I think you don't add .h files to them, only .c and .lib and .dll.